Hbuilderx compilation of uniapp code reported an error. File save refresh error
enter image description here
Console error，eslint error，[eslint-vue] 09:46:57.911 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
[eslint-vue] 09:46:57.911     at resolveSettings (D:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\HBuilderX.3.95.2023102806\HBuilderX\plugins\eslint-js\out\extension.js:93:25)
[eslint-vue] 09:46:57.911     at validateAndFixDocument (D:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\HBuilderX.3.95.2023102806\HBuilderX\plugins\eslint-js\out\extension.js:156:17)
[eslint-vue] 09:46:57.912     at D:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\HBuilderX.3.95.2023102806\HBuilderX\plugins\eslint-js\out\extension.js:299:4
[eslint-vue] 09:46:57.912     at D:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\HBuilderX.3.95.2023102806\HBuilderX\plugins\plugin-manager\out.js:1:93745
[eslint-vue] 09:46:57.912     at D:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\HBuilderX.3.95.2023102806\HBuilderX\plugins\plugin-manager\out.js:1:356566
[eslint-vue] 09:46:57.912     at D:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\HBuilderX.3.95.2023102806\HBuilderX\plugins\plugin-manager\out.js:1:357640
[eslint-vue] 09:46:57.912     at Immediate._onImmediate (D:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\HBuilderX.3.95.2023102806\HBuilderX\plugins\plugin-manager\out.js:1:360025)
[eslint-vue] 09:46:57.912     at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:466:21)
I hope that this error will not occur after each refresh, and there will be no error when saving automatically

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Whenever I format code, this error appears in my console
